# Android :: Twitter Exception on using Twitter4j library

Tags: android, twitter4j

I tried to use the code at http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/04/using-twitter4j-to-tweet-in-android.html. But on using it, I receive `TwitterException` and hence I am not able to send the tweet.

Comment: Put the whole logcat error that you receive. And the part of the code where this error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... it will work for me ..

```
 EditText status="test Message from Android ";
 twitter = new Twitter(username, password);
String token = "Your Token ID";
String secret = "Your Secret Code";
twitter4j.Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a); 
try {
       twitter.updateStatus(status.getText().toString());
} catch (TwitterException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Aren't you using twitter variable two times. Won't it cause error